# Add a dimension to an associative array

Tags: php

I have an array of default settings, that needs to be an associative array, it allows me to merge it with an array of settings saved in database:

```
$defaults = array ( 'eswc_redirect' => false,
                    'eswc_remove_shop_title' => false,
                    'eswc_remove_footer_credits' => 'Yes',
                  );
```

I would like it to store more parameters for the same settings, not just its value, for example type that I will later use to properly sanitize all the settings in a loop.

I expect to have over 50 settings and I need to make it as simple as possible, without double or triple typing the same. I would like to have everything related to a single setting written in one line like this (I expect it not to work, it's just to show my intent):

```
$defaults = array ( array ( 'eswc_redirect' => false, 'checkbox' ),
                    array ( 'eswc_remove_shop_title' => false, 'checkbox' ),
                    array ( 'eswc_remove_footer_credits' => 'Yes', 'text' ),
                  );
```

As a PHP novice, I would gladly see an example of how to access data from such an array in a loop.

I would also need to extract an array as presented in my 1st piece of code from this new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be better to keep it as an associative array, but make the values nested associative arrays.

```
$defaults = ['eswc_redirect' => ['value' => false, 'type' => 'checkbox' ],
             'eswc_remove_shop_title' => ['value' => false, 'type' => 'checkbox' ],
             'eswc_remove_footer_credits' => ['value' => 'Yes', 'type' => 'text' ],
    ];
```

Then you access it like `$defaults['eswc_redirect']['value']`

Answer (score 0):

You can have many arrays in an array, for example:

```
$defaults = [
    'settings' => [
        'eswc_redirect' => false,
        'eswc_remove_shop_title' => false,
        'eswc_remove_footer_credits' => 'Yes'
    ],
    'database_connection' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'user' => 'root',
        'pass' => ''
    ]
];
```

And you can easily access each configuration, for example:

```
$defaults['settings']['eswc_redirect']
```

and

```
$defaults['database_connection']['user']
```

Comment: How will I be able to assign 'checkbox' to 'eswc_redirect' in such an implementation?